# Possible to inherit from WebClient without my code being a "design time component"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, components, webclient

I have a piece of code like this:

```
public class NoFollowWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Whenever I add this to a .cs file though, Visual Studio 2012, in it's infinite wisdom, converts my C# source file to a "design time component". So, when I double click on the file now, instead of seeing my C# code, I see "To add components to your class, drag them from the Toolbox and use the Properties window to set their properties".

I know I can right click and do "view code", but that's extremely annoying.

Is there anyway to force Visual Studio to not assume I'm making a component or that I care about their stupid visual designer that serves no purpose for my class?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the `csproj` file XML. Make sure it's marked as a `<Compile Include="....\NoFollowWebClient.cs" />` kind of entry. EDIT: Perhaps it's marked as a completely different kind of file; make sure it doesn't have a `<SubType>Designer</SubType>` child tag under it.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that Visual Studio will automatically add

```
<SubType>Component</SubType>
```

in your .csproj file as soon as you inherit from WebClient. Even if you try to remove this, Visual Studio adds it again when you reopen the project.

A solution is to add the following attribute to your class.

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
```

Comment: In VS2013, I used the following tips from another thread, and everything worked fine: 1. Use the full System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory, don't rely on a using. 2. Edit the .csproj file and remove the <SubType>Component</SubType> from the Compile tag for the class (and to be safe, I modified the Compile tag to be self-closing, like the others). This is easily undone by accident, so you may find yourself doing it more than once if you modify your class.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Work well in Visual Studio 2017. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Class with System.ComponentModel.Component on their inheritance path are automatically treated as "components" within Visual Studio

(Unfortunately) WebClient has System.ComponentModel.Component in its inheritance path: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx